# Jest config is not correctly recognizing the files to test upon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have the current folder structure (where test is in the root of my directory):

```
test
    unit
        helper
            helper.js
        helper2
            helper2.js
```

My `jest.config.js` looks like the following (this config file is in the root of my folder):

```
module.exports = {
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    collectCoverage: true,
    collectCoverageFrom: ['**/*.{js,jsx}', '!**/node_modules/**'],
    coverageDirectory: './coverage',
    roots: ['<rootDir>/test'],
    coverageReporters: ['text'],
    rootDir: '.',
    reporters: ['default'],
};
```

When I run the command: `jest --verbose` I am getting the error that `No tests found, existing with code 1`. Is there something wrong in my jest config that I need to modify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even that you've modified the `roots` jest still has [testMatch](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testmatch-arraystring). By default it's value is

```json
"testMatch": [
  "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)",
  "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)"
],
```

so you can change it to:

```json
"testMatch": [
  "**/*.[jt]s?(x)",
],
```

**Note:** by running `jest --showConfig` you'll get a nice overview of all of the configurations and an idea of what else might need to be changed

Comment: Should I add `"**/*.[jt]s?(x)"` in the `collectCoverageFrom` key as well? For some reason it shows the coverage table but shows 0% under statements, branch, functions, and lines. So not sure if the coverage collection is working.

Comment: Hmm odd it doesn't show any coverage or the files in the coverage report.

Comment: @CapturedTree you can try instead of modifying the root - changing the `testMatch` to `['test/**/*.[jt]s?(x)']`